# How do I end this Loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Yes this a school assignent and as of right now i feel pretty stupid

I'm trying to get the program to count files in a directory, store that value in a variable, *RecipeCount* and then run a loop to grab the filenames of the counted files and list them (works just fine)

When I added my next line of code to add an integer to each file grabbed, i found myself stuck in the loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class RecipeBook {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Variables 
    String CarriageReturn = System.getProperty("line.separator"); //This will retrieve line separator dependent on OS

    String RecipeDirectory;
    int RecipeCount;
    Scanner UserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int RecipeLoopCounter= 0; 

    //Display Application info

    System.out.println("Recipe Book V0.13" + CarriageReturn);

            //Locate Recipe Directory and count Recipes

            System.out.println("First Run Detected!"+ CarriageReturn +"Where are your recipes located?");

                 RecipeDirectory =  UserInput.nextLine();
                 RecipeCount = new File(RecipeDirectory).list().length;


            System.out.println("Folder Scanned - Found " + RecipeCount + " Recipes");
            System.out.println("--------------------Recipe Index--------------------");


            File directory = new File(RecipeDirectory);

            //get all the files from a directory
            File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
                 for (File file : fList){
                 if (file.isFile()){
            System.out.println(file.getName());

            System.out.println("Enter 1-"+ RecipeCount + "to select a recipe card" );
```

Comment: You're missing code, and you need to format the code you have.

Comment: OK, I've formatted the code you've posted, but you still need to show us where you close your if block and where you close your for loop.

Comment: I think i just forgot to close both and now i'm just lost...

Comment: @user3015616 If you were "stuck in the loop", the code must compile, but what you've shown us won't compile because the loop and if statements aren't closed. Paste the full code and we'll be able to help.

Comment: This question would best be answered by your reading and studying your textbook since the problem is that you don't understand the basics of Java syntax. Don't rely on the IDE -- understand the language. In the future, you'll want to ask more informative questions from the get-go, rather than force us to drag information out of you. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//get all the files from a directory
File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
for (File file : fList){
    if (file.isFile()){
        System.out.println(file.getName());
    }// end if 
}// end for 

System.out.println("Enter 1-"+ RecipeCount + "to select a recipe card" );
```

This should work.

Comment: Maybe you want to share what code got you stuck in the loop ? Meaning the full code with e braces *{}*

Comment: that was my last block... so it still ran...and the IDE didnt pick missing bracers up

Comment: rather than *stuck in the loop* . I believed you have compilation error.